# ios8 avfoundation camera freeze upon start

Tags: camera, ios8, avfoundation, freeze

My camera freezes when the app starts. The only way to unfreeze it is to go back to the home screen (without closing the app) and reopening it.

I have used `[session startRunning]`in my ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear, but nothing works. Before my phone ran iOS 8, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add the [session startRunning] in the main thread just like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (![session isRunning]) {              
        [session startRunning];
    }
});
```